# When creating an Azure Storage AppendBlob I can't see it in portal/storage explorer - 409 conflict

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to use the new AppendBlob

This is my code:

```
        CloudAppendBlob appendBlob = container.GetAppendBlobReference("MyDir/MyKey");
        if (!appendBlob.Exists())
        {
            appendBlob.CreateOrReplace();
        }
        return appendBlob.AppendTextAsync("someText");
```

If I do DownloadText on the given reference I see the text I put in ("someTextsomeTextsomeTextsomeText").

But if I go to the portal to see the blob I get the error message "Cannot load management data for the current view."

And if i  try to use the storage explorer I get "The remote server returned an error: (409) Conflict."

Can anyone explain these errors to me and how to resolve them?

Thanks!

Comment: What storage explorer are you using?

Comment: I tried both Storage Explorer 6 and the Web Storage Explorer both gave me the 409 error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Support for `Append Blob` is introduced in Storage Service REST API Version `2015-02-21`. Storage Client library version 5.0.0 has support for this REST API version.

The reason you're getting this error is most likely because these tools are not updated to make use of latest version of REST API/Storage Client library.

One thing you could do is contact the owners of these tools and ask them to update the code to make use of latest version of REST API/Storage Client library. Azure Storage Explorer is open source so you may want to take the code and update it so that it makes use of the latest library.

If you're looking for other tools, you can either look at [`Cloud Portam`](http://www.cloudportam.com) [Disclaimer: I am building this tool] (http://blog.cloudportam.com/announcing-support-for-append-blobs-in-cloud-portam/) or [`Azure Management Studio`](http://www.cerebrata.com/). Both of these tools have full support for Append Blobs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I assumed that was the case for the external tools, but i'm mostly wondering about the azure management portal error, it doesn't make sense that they wouldn't support their own update in their own portal, right?

Comment: It can happen :). For example if you use AzCopy today, it still works on the old version of storage client library.